# only pull back records with json keys in postgresql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a json blob filled with dates that contain sets of data and I need to pull back only records that contain that date.

If the json blob were jsonb I could use
"select * from "table" where json_blob ? '2014-07-03';"

The db is enormous so I don't want to convert it to jsonb does anyone know how I can do this simple json query without the new data type?  When I try to use 
"select * from "table" where json_blob::json->'2014-07-03' is not null;"

it cannot do a boolean operation on a json object it didn't find